# How do I modify dataframe rows based on another dataframe in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df2 such as:

```
ID | data
--------
1 | New
3 | New 
5 | New
```

and a main dataframe, df1:

```
ID | data | more
----------------
1 | OLD | a
2 | OLD | b
3 | OLD | c
4 | OLD | d
5 | OLD | e
```

I want to achieve something of the sort:

```
ID | data | more
----------------
1 | NEW | a
2 | OLD | b
3 | NEW | c
4 | OLD | d
5 | NEW | e
```

I want to update df1 based on df2, keeping the original values of df1 when they dont exist in df2.

Is there a fast way to do this than using isin? Isin is very slow when df1 and df2 are both very large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With left join and "coalesce":

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, "OLD", "a"),
  (2, "OLD", "b"),
  (3, "OLD", "c"),
  (4, "OLD", "d"),
  (5, "OLD", "e")).toDF("ID", "data", "more")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1, "New"),
  (3, "New"),
  (5, "New")).toDF("ID", "data")

// action
val result = df1.alias("df1")
  .join(
    df2.alias("df2"),$"df2.ID" === $"df1.ID", "left")
  .select($"df1.ID",
    coalesce($"df2.data", $"df1.data").alias("data"),
    $"more")
```

Output:

```
+---+----+----+
|ID |data|more|
+---+----+----+
|1  |New |a   |
|2  |OLD |b   |
|3  |New |c   |
|4  |OLD |d   |
|5  |New |e   |
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for dynamic columns and not listing all columns in the select statement?